# WHERE AND statement in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following MySQL statement to get Drupal posts where the IDs match across tables:

```
SELECT node.nid,node_revisions.nid,url_alias.nid, 1, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), node_revisions.body, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.teaser, url_alias.slug, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.changed), if(node.type='blog', 'post', 'page')
FROM node, node_revisions, url_alias 
WHERE (node.type='blog' OR node.type='page') 
AND (node.nid=node_revisions.nid) 
AND (node.nid=url_alias.nid)
LIMIT 10;
```

(note that I've done some modifications to url_alias, if anyone is trying to duplicates this)

I have to use two AND statements, because, for some reason, this won't work:

```
...
WHERE ...
AND (node.nid=node_revisions.nid=url_alias.nid)
...
```

Why can't I compare the IDs all in one AND statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL doesn't work like that.  MySQL only accepts single pairs of binary comparisons.  Most programming languages would behave like you want, but SQL is not a programming language.  Writing the joins explicitly will help with the readability of the query and might be a work around for what you're trying to do.  The query could be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT nid, 1, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), node_revisions.body, node_revisions.title,
    node_revisions.teaser, url_alias.slug, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.changed),
    if(node.type='blog', 'post', 'page')
FROM node
    JOIN node_revisions USING (nid)
    LEFT JOIN url_alias USING (nid)
WHERE node.type IN ('blog','page')
LIMIT 10
```

I also change the three `nid` columns in the select to one since the will always be the same, made the post type condition an `IN` clause since that optimizes better, and made the `JOIN` with `url_aliases` a `LEFT JOIN` in case a node doesn't have an alias.

Comment: this looks awesome.  I haven't gotten into using JOIN yet, or LEFT JOIN, so I don't really understand it yet, but it seems much more readable, I agree.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a good solution, but not a good answer.  The other answers actually detail why I can't compare the IDs in one AND statement.  Could you add this to your answer so I can mark yours as correct?

Comment: @bozdoz I added a more in-depth answer to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

The = comparator in SQL is binary.  a=b=c is never allowed in any context.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the syntax you provided can be interpreted a couple of ways.

The intuitive human way which you are driving at, in which you could write the equivalent

```
(node.nid=node_revisions.nid) AND (node_revisions.nid=url_alias.nid)
```

And the way a computer might interpret it simply addressing operations left to right:

```
(node.nid=node_revisions.nid)=url_alias.nid
```

That is, to analyze whether url_alias.nid equals the true/false (or really 0/1, in this case) result of the previous equality.  This is not trivial, the results of boolean operations are often treated as variables and compared directly this way.

Answer (score 1):

In programming languages (although SQL is not one) a comparison returns a boolean and unparenthesized multi calculations are made respecting the order of signs and then from left to right. So if it was PHP

`$a == $b == 3` would compile into
`($a == $b) == 3` which would compile into
`true == 3` or `false == 3` accordingly